# Cannot connect to google cloudsql from app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have been trying the past 2 days to connect to the cloudsql from the appengine, I am able to connect from a linux webserver via the IP, however cannot from the app engine with the same setup.

My connection string is as follows: 
please note the actual appid was replaced as well as the dbname

in app.yaml

```
env_variables:
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/appid:us-central1:sql-instance-1;dbname=dbname
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
```

In the phpfile

```
$dsn = getenv('MYSQL_DSN');
$user = getenv('MYSQL_USER');
$password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
if (!isset($dsn, $user) || false === $password) {
    throw new Exception('Set MYSQL_DSN, MYSQL_USER, and MYSQL_PASSWORD environment variables');
}
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

The above was obtained from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/
I have tried with using a password, and not using a password. I have tried the username root, as username with a password and a username without.

I am using second generation setup, and flex php environment, the error I keep receiving is the following:

Short error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Full error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /app/dbconn.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /app/dbconn.php(12): PDO->__construct('mysql:unix_sock...', 'root', '') #1 /app/api.user.php(2): include_once('/app/dbconn.php') #2 {main} thrown in /app/dbconn.php on line 12
```

I am truly out of ideas now. Please note that both sql and app are in the same project.

Comment: could you manage to resolve the issue ? I am getting the same one.

Comment: @IlkerBaltaci I never found a solution, and ended up using their VM/Compute engine rather.

Answer (score 7):

If you SSH into on of your instances (this will put it in debug mode) you can check for the existence of the socket file. You can open a connection from the Cloud Console.

Then,

```
ls /cloudsql
```

This directory should contain an item the named `<project-id>:<region>:<instance-name>`, following your `MYSQL_DSN` environment variable.

If it's not there, make sure that you've **enabled the relevant APIs**. In the documentation page [Using Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql), follow the instructions under "Before you begin" -- specifically "Enable the API". (Your logs may also notify you about this: "Access Not Configured. Cloud SQL Administration API has not been used in project  before or it is disabled.") Wait a few minutes after enabling the API before you **redeploy**.

You may have done this already, but in my experience it's a step that's easy to overlook.

Also, **make sure that your app.yaml file contains the following**:

```
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "<project-id>:<region>:<instance-name>"
```

Lastly, try putting the value of **`MYSQL_DSN` in app.yaml file in quotes**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried ls /cloudsql with the following result: ls: cannot access /cloudsql: No such file or directory , I also made sure the API was enabled. As the end I just used a compute engine as I could not find a solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include another possibility. Make sure that you have the `beta_settings` values set correctly.

Comment: @Subash do you see the same error as the original poster, or a different one? If it's the same, check your logs for "Access Not Configured" messages.

Comment: @subash try the quotes that i mentioned

Comment: unfortunately, i am getting the same error... i think it's because the `/cloudsql` directory is not available, even though i've enabled the API.
does anyone know, how to solve this?

Comment: you may need to remove the instances to create a new one now with the api enabled.

Comment: If the `/cloudsql` directory is not there, you may still need to create the directory and start the proxy to create the file socket, per [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql). e.g. `sudo mkdir /cloudsql; sudo chmod 777 /cloudsql` , then `wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy` , `chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy`, `./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql &`. Did that work for you?